# Find and replace the whole string when a partial match is achieved multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am New to Excel VBA and next to write code to Find and replace the whole string when a partial match is achieved multiple sheets.

Find must be used as I am searching in cells with a formula but want to change the value displayed.

The items I would like to search for and replace are all in a column on another sheet. I have provided pictures to better explain.

I believe it should look something like

```
'Replace the whole string when a partial match is achieved
'find -findobj = sheet.find
'if find finds - does findobj have data
'replace in findobj
'Replace the whole string when a partial match is achieved
```

Being new its been hard for me to come up with something so any suggestions or help would be great.

[image: pics to Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer will use the cells in the first sheet and check them against the cells in the second and third sheets (just change `For x = 2 To 3` to whatever to change what sheets it targets).

```
Sub PartialReplace()
Dim wsO As Worksheet, wsX As Worksheet
Dim x As Long
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

'set original worksheet as first sheet
Set wsO = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'set range to find values from
Set rng1 = NonBlankCells(wsO)

'loop through all cells to find values from
For Each cell1 In rng1
    
    'loop through 2nd and 3rd sheets
    For x = 2 To 3
        
        Set wsX = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(x)
        
        'find all cells to check on sheet being checked
        Set rng2 = NonBlankCells(wsX)
        
        'loop through all cells on sheet being checked
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            For Each cell2 In rng2
                
                'if partial match, replace cell value
                If cell2.Text Like "*" & cell1.Text & "*" Then
                    cell2.Value = cell1.Value
                End If
                
            Next cell2
        End If

        Set rng2 = Nothing
        
    Next x

Next cell1

Set rng1 = Nothing

End Sub

Function NonBlankCells(ws As Worksheet) As Range
Dim ct1 As Long, ct2 As Long

On Error Resume Next
ct1 = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
ct2 = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Count
On Error GoTo 0

If ct1 > 0 And ct2 = 0 Then
    Set NonBlankCells = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
ElseIf ct1 = 0 And ct2 > 0 Then
    Set NonBlankCells = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
ElseIf ct1 > 0 And ct2 > 0 Then
    Set NonBlankCells = Union( _
    ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), _
    ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I will post what I have next time.@J.Fox

Comment: If cell2.Value Like "*" & cell1.Value & "*" Then   i changed this to If cell2.Text Like "*" & cell1.Text & "*" works like a charm. @J.Fox